# The Equivalent of indexof

Tags: go

I am trying to find out the equivalent of indexof to get the position of specific element in array golang the purpose for integers in array.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("what")

    arr := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 5, 4, 4, 1, 6}

    i := IndexOf(2, arr)

}
```

Comment: like getting the position of an integer in array.

Comment: Go does not have such methods, you need to add on your own.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8307478/9681220

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no equivalent for `IndexOf` in Go. You need to implement one your self. But if you have have sorted array of Ints, you can use `sort.SearchInts` as shown below.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(sort.SearchInts([]int{2,3,4,5,9,10,11}, 5))
}
```

Also from the godoc:

*SearchInts searches for x in a sorted slice of ints and returns the index as specified by Search. The return value is the index to insert x if x is not present (it could be len(a)). The slice must be sorted in ascending order.*

Comment: This works only if the `arr` is sorted.  In that case, it's not necessary to call `sort.IntSlice(arr)` as shown in the ansswer.  Because the slice in the question is not sorted, this answer does not apply to the question.

Comment: Clearly it is evident from his question he is asking for a generic function which does the job. This solution works only for sorted slices.

Comment: Ok may be i should not have taken the the example from the question above. This was more of a FYI answer. I will edit the code to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Write a function.  Here's an example assuming that `IndexOf` returns the first index of the number or -1 if none is found.

```
// IndexOf returns the first index of needle in haystack
// or -1 if needle is not in haystack.
func IndexOf(haystack []int, needle int) int {
    for i, v := range haystack {
        if v == needle {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

[Run this code on the Go Programming Language Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vanMFlS0dii).

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func IndexOf(arr []int, candidate int) int {
    for index, c := range arr {
        if c == candidate {
            return index
        }
    }
    return -1
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("what")
    arr := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 5, 4, 4, 1, 6}
    i := IndexOf(arr, 2)
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

Add a method IndexOf to search, this is a linear search method.

Ref: https://play.golang.org/p/Hp6Dg--XoIV

Answer (score 1):

There is no common library function to do this for you in go.

However if you are using a byte slice, you can use [IndexByte(b []byte, c byte) int](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#IndexByte).

Or you can write a quick function which does this for you:

```
func indexOf(arr []int, val int) int {
    for pos, v := range arr {
        if v == val {
            return pos
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```